# promise all with lists and append inside

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have two functions that contains Async operation which return a list. I use promise all to execute them in same time.
The first list works but the second shows me an undefined.

```
let content = "<div class='clsLines'>";

return Promise.all([
    firstList()
]).then((messages) => {
    content+= messages
    secondList()
}).then((messages) => {
    content+= messages
   
    content+="</div>"; // close clsLinesDiv
    $('#id').find('.cls').append(content); // append the lists in a div
});
```

How can i display the second list instead of the undefined?
Should closing div and append be inside or outside the promise

Thank you !

Comment: You are not executing them at the same time. You are starting `secondList()` after `firstList()`. But regardless, you are seeing what you are seeing because you are missing a `return` statement: `secondList()` -> `return secondList();`.

Comment: Your `then` callbacks should *return* the promised value that the next one should receive.

Comment: Your `Promise.all` is pretty useless, as you're only passing one promise in. It should be `Promise.all([firstList(), secondList()])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing them at the same time. You are starting `secondList()` after `firstList()`. But regardless, you are seeing what you are seeing because you are missing a `return` statement. It should be

```
.then((messages) => {
    content+= messages
    return secondList()
})
```

However you could really execute those promises "in parallel" and avoid shared variables:

```
Promise.all([firstList(), secondList()])
  .then(([firstResult, secondResult]) => {
    $('#id').find('.cls')
      .append(`<div class='clsLines'>${firstResult}${secondResult}</div>`);
  })
```